# What security type is best for WCF (wsHttpBinding) Service and its Client sitting cross domain, and both uses same database

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, authentication

So I have a WCF service i.e. a Proxy Service having Internet connection and hosted in Windows Service, which I want to expose wsHttpBinding.

Client for it is another WCF service (hosted in IIS) but has no Internet connection and uses Proxy service cross domain.

I am not able to connect that using wsHttpBinding unless I change Security Mode to "None".

What would be the best security authentication and configuration for this environment?

They both uses same database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you indicated you’re not able to connect unless you change the Security Mode to ‘None’, I suspect this is because of your ClientCredentialType setting.  WsHttpBinding defaults to ‘Windows’ for the client credential.  This works great when client and service are in the same domain.  Since you’re crossing security realms (domains), consider using ‘UserName’ as your client credential type instead.

Here is a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

As for which is best, that’s hard to say with the limited amount of information here.  However, here’s a link to [Common Security Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730301%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with guidance on how to configure your services for each.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, "Common Security Scenarios" link is very useful.